# Clipping a photo to a rounded gradient background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, gradient, photo-editing, filter

I have a photo I removed the background from, leaving only the human models - 3 people sitting in front of a computer. I need the new background to be gradient filled and the left bottom corner of the image to have a 3px rounded corner so it can be incorporated into a Website slider with the same rounded corner. The new photo will be placed at the left-side of the slider.

Using Photoshop, the photo is on layer #1, a gradient filled rectangle with rounded corners is on layer #2. All but the left bottom corner of the rounded-corner rectangle is dragged off the visible canvas.

When I clip the photo using layer #2 the photo takes on the gradient fill completely obscuring the people - all I have is a gradient filled layer. How do I clip the photo to the gradient filled rectangle, producing a photo of 3 people with a gradient background and the left bottom corner rounded? I would prefer the photo remain editable because I have smart filters applied.

Note: I was able to accomplish this by merging layers and then clipping to a rounded rectangle but this effectively destroyed any chance of future editing the photo with the original filters.

Comment: Can you post a sample image? (Just link to it and someone with enough rep will add it to the question.) I'm having some difficulty envisioning what the problem is. If you removed the background from the people, the gradient layer should show through.

Comment: consider grouping the gradient and the people, and then apply a rounded-rectangle *as a layer mask* on the group. This decouples the gradient from the rounded corners.

Comment: horatio got it right however I see no mechanism to award the correct answer.

Comment: FWIW, you should be able to handle the rounded corner directly on the web page via CSS.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your question:

1. Right click the icon for layer 1, hit select pixels.
2. Go to select, select inverse.
3. Click on layer 2, hit ctrl + x.